# Find all the possible ways a word can be split by syllables

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm not sure how best to word this question, but given the word `pineapple`, and given it's syllables in an array like `["pine", "ap", "ple"]`, I need to find all the possible ways the word can be split by it's syllables. The function would produce the following result:

`[["pineapple"], ["pine", "apple"], ["pine", "ap", "ple"], ["pineap", "ple"]]`

I believe I've come across a very similar leetcode/algoexpert type question before, but can't seem to remember exactly what it was.

Note: the syllables must be in order so [“pineple”, “ap”] is not valid.

Comment: Use combinations or permutations (like two sum) except you probably need to specify what your target length is?

Comment: What about `[pineple, ap]`?

Comment: results can be of any length. the syllables must be in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given N syllables of the word, there are N-1 positions *between* syllables.  For each such position, you can decide whether to split the word there or join them together.  There are 2<sup>N-1</sup> ways to make those choices, and each one will product a different partition of the word.

Here's a simple iterative way to make those choices by counting from 0 to 2<sup>N-1</sup> and using each bit in the current count to decide one split:

```py
def splits(syls):
    if len(syls) < 2:
        return syls
    for count in range(1<<(len(syls)-1)):
        list = [syls[0]]
        for pos in range(1,len(syls)):
            if (count & (1<<(pos-1))) == 0:
                list[-1]+=syls[pos]
            else:
                list.append(syls[pos])
        print(list)

splits(["pine", "ap", "ple"])
```

Output:

```
['pineapple']
['pine', 'apple']    
['pineap', 'ple']    
['pine', 'ap', 'ple']
```

Answer (score 1):

In python the spelling is `["pine", "ap", "ple"]`,
but in TeX it would be spelled `pine-ap-ple`, same thing.
The vector of N+1 syllables suggests a vector of N
punctuation marks, where the mark could be "`-`" hyphen
or "" empty.

This is identical to a bit vector of length N.
So we need merely count.

0. `00` --> "", "", or pineapple
1. `01` --> "", "-", or pineap-ple
2. `10` --> "-", "", or pine-apple
3. `11` --> "-", "-", or pine-ap-ple

You can see that with

```
fmt = f'0{n}b'  # e.g. '02b'
for i in range(2 ** n):
    print(format(i, fmt))
```

Then it's just a matter of assembling the corresponding list.

Comment: what needs to be changed for a list of length `n`?

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools.product` with [True, False]:

True: do split

False: dont split

```py
from itertools import product

A = ["pine", "ap", "ple"]
ans = []
for comb in product([True, False], repeat=len(A) - 1):
    comb = [True] + list(comb)
    a = []
    for doSplit, syllables in zip(comb, A):
        if doSplit:
            a.append(syllables)
        else:
            a[-1] += syllables
    ans.append(a)
print(ans)
```

```
[['pine', 'ap', 'ple'], ['pine', 'apple'], ['pineap', 'ple'], ['pineapple']]
```